Why don't women continue to produce ova indefinitely?
Why has the human body not evolved to produce more ova?
Is there some technical reason that makes is easy while the fetus is developing, but much harder later in life?
Or, perhaps more likely, is it just that during the majority of the evolution of our species, people would not have lived long enough that menopause would be a significant factor, combined with the quite long gestational period, whereas a male can fertilise comparatively far more in the same period; thus the ability to indefinitely produce sperm is far more valuable?

Welcome to Biology.SE! There may not be a good answer to your specific question, so I'd suggest reading Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?

they probably aren't , https://www.nih.gov/news-events/nih-research-matters/egg-producing-stem-cells-found-women your question might be better considered as why does menopause exist. in either case one question at a time, this fails the would a complete answer be a textbook check.

Most female mammals have reduced or no ability to reproduce in later years. Why should humans be different? If anything, it's an advantage, as it allows for a longer lifespan. Having babies is taxing (both before birth and after.) Having an extended family, e.g. grandmothers with life experience, able to share in caring for family members is beneficial. Teleological arguments, admittedly, but so is the question.

Welcome to SE Biology. I have edited your question to remove the misuse of the word "finite" and put your question it into plain English. Even though we are scientists, we understand and even prefer this. I have also removed your irrelevant and incorrect paragraph about oocytes. If you want to know what an oocyte is you can look it up on Wikipedia: it is a precursor of a mature ovum.

Also, there's a consideration of mutations. Germline mutation rates in sperm increase substantially with age, but remain consistently lower in oocytes throughout the woman's reproductive life. I imagine having completed all meiotic division by the time they are born contributes to this low and consistent rate of germ-line mutations. It also makes sense evolutionarily considering the resources females expend on gestation, birthing, and parenting. They more invested in the genetic fidelity of the offspring, whereas males are built for quantity more than than quality.

Maybe because it's better to have the mother present to care for the offspring for childhood and adolescence. Assuming menopause occurs at 45-55 years of age and the average life expectancy of a female is 75 years, there is an overlap of 25 years on average. I don't know if this makes sense, especially when we consider that life expectancy used to be much lower, around 30 years on average throughout history and that old mothers are less able to take care of children anyway. The latter is more plausible; older mothers are less capable of child care.

Just to add a postscript, the fundamental difficulty with the specific question from biological viewpoint is we evolved as a species as hunter-gathers and most of that history has been erased. Urbanisation/"civilisation" has only occurred for our species for at best 5% of its history (more like 2.5% and less).
Society and survival are very different for hunter-gatherers; I once attended a talk by a PNAS Academy member whose work specialised in the differences. What's a norm to us, is weird to hunter-gathers because we do stuff that has no practical benefit for survival.
Purely as wild speculation the menopause in hunter-gather societies could have had a pivotal advantage, such as the extensive knowledge, or knowledge base, leveraged via kin selection.
Survival and eventual dominance of our species was a consequence of adaptation to selection pressure.

Original answer
This is a really good question, because few other species are known to go through menopause, one of these is the killer whale (as well as the pilot whale and toothed whales). The phenomenon in killer whales has been subject to extensive studies.
To specifically answer your question, I don't know. Given the research and debate in killer whales I'd suggest that menopause here (i.e. specific to whales) is an important evolutionary strategy that enhances the overall success of the pod.

In female killer whales, menopause typically occurs around the age of 40 to 50 years, and they can live another 30 to 40 years after they stop reproducing.
There are loads of hypotheses of why killer whales have a menopause, these include but are not limited to:

Mother hypothesis
Grandmother Hypothesis or Ecological hypothesis

Point 1 has been well researched and the idea is that female orcas select mates on the size of the male, i.e. how physically big the male orca. This selection pressure is extreme one male orca can sire offspring from multiple females. Male killer whales, unlike females, continue reproducing throughout their lives. So the selective pressure is for the mother not to maximise the number of offspring but to have bigger sons (and grandsons). They do this by feeding their sons throughout their lives, the menopause is considered part of this process, to ensure resources are maximised on maximising the reproductive success of their sons. Thus the idea is the more the male orcas eat, the bigger they get.
Point 2. Kin Selection. The idea is that the menopause in orcas enhances the survival and reproductive success of their descendants by focusing on helping raise and protect younger generations. Reproduction has cost in longevity. One very clear mechanism is the pod is a matriarchy and the older females retain extensive knowledge, for example of a diverse range of feeding grounds. Their knowledge can be invaluable for helping younger generations find food and survive in changing conditions.
Summary. Instead of reproducing, older female killer whales invest their time and energy into helping their offspring and grandchildren survive and thrive.

Citations: "Menopause in killer whales: A review of the evidence"
This is a really good Nature journal podcast presented as a YouTube video. Highly recommended.

As extracted from reference source:

The ovaries are filled with follicles. Follicles are fluid-filled structures in which the oocyte (also called egg) grows to maturity. Current knowledge indicates that females are born with their entire lifetime supply of gametes. At birth, the normal female ovary contains about 1-2 million/oocytes (eggs). Females are not capable of making new eggs, and in fact, there is a continuous decline in the total number of eggs each month. By the time a girl enters puberty, only about 25% of her lifetime total egg pool remains, around 300,000. Over the next 30-40 years of a female's reproductive life, the entire egg supply will be depleted. Although no one can know with absolute certainty the number of eggs remaining within the ovaries at any given time, most women begin to experience a significant decrease in fertility (the ability to conceive a child) around the age of 37. At the time of menopause, virtually no eggs remain.


The large supplies of eggs within each ovary are immature, or primordial, and must undergo growth and maturation each month. The eggs are stored within follicles in the ovary. Within a woman's lifespan, large numbers of follicles and oocytes will be recruited to begin the growth and maturation process. The large majority, however, will not reach full maturity. Most will die off in a process called atresia. Thus, only about 300-500 of these eggs will mature over a women's life span.

https://www.rogelcancercenter.org/fertility-preservation/for-female-patients/normal-ovarian-function#:~:text=At%20the%20time%20of%20menopause,within%20follicles%20in%20the%20ovary.
